# the database doesn't change after my insert command is executed

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

```
String insertUser = "Insert into Users (FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, Password, BirthDate, PhoneNumber)" +
                    "values ('"+ FirstNameTextbox.Text + "','" + LastNameTextbox.Text + "','" + 
                EmailTextbox.Text + "','" + PasswordTextbox.Text + "','" + 
                BirthDateDateTimePicker.Value +  "','" + PhoneNumberTextbox.Text + "');";

SqlCommand addUser = new SqlCommand(insertUser,scn);
addUser.ExecuteNonQuery();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Users",scn);
da.Fill(ds, "Users");

MessageBox.Show("Account created successfully");
```

The message is shown, but the database is still the same .

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: How are you checking the database? Are you querying it or are you looking at the result of `da.Fill(ds, "Users");` ? Put a break point in that code and look at the connection string for `scn` and make sure it points to where you think it points.

Comment: Do you have a Transaction going on? Is the Transaction commited?

Comment: The line `addUser.ExecuteNonQuery();` returns a count of the effected rows, what value do you get returned?